# Add row but appending extra html to each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm facing adding new row using Datatable here.

I expect the newly appended html would remain at the bottom of my tr when I append the every custom html. Strange it refreshed so only the first click is working. I've created a demo below :

https://jsfiddle.net/gvowhrmp/

```
function appendRow(name, position, office, age, date,salary) {
    var t = $('#example').DataTable();

    var node = t.row.add([
      name,
      position,
      office,
      age,
      date,
      salary,
    ]).draw().node();

    var detail_row = '';

    detail_row = '<h3>Custom HTML</h3>';

    $(node).addClass('result-row');

    node = node.outerHTML += detail_row;

    $(node).hide().fadeIn('normal');
  }
```

Comment: When I click the button in your jsfiddle it adds a row every time i clcik the button. So what do you mean by that it works only once

Comment: @Imprfectluck the table got refreshed and the previous added html gone. It seems like it's working for the first click, but actually from 2nd click on ward you can see the htmls is gone.

Comment: well the html seems to  remain for me. check this screenshot https://snag.gy/pEcVJu.jpg

Comment: @Imprfectluck I concate the node with customHTML, I expect under each tr, the customHTML underneath it. try click 4 times, and it will have only ONE customHTML.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It seems you want to inject a `<h3>` to the `<tr>` of the newly created row? This is bad markup.

Comment: You jsfiddle works fine for me. What's wrong with that? Please clearly explain what is that you are expecting? If the datatable contains rows more than 10 it is added to the second page and if it exceeds 20 it adds to 3rd page and so on. And you get a pagination link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Lucky, it does not work - if you turn sorting on, or filter, you will see that the inserted disappears. Besides clearing up what OP really try to accomplish, this is also a matter of doing that "what" properly.